# how to make grid like free structure with CSS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to make this grid-like structure in CSS:

[image]

the key is all columns must have the same width but free height for their content, and all be equally spaced between, and the length of content is dynamic

for example this is my content:

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <p>new test post</p>
    <p><img src="/file/169418062091746619.png" width="165" height="135"></p>
    <p>This is the new post</p>
  <div>
  <div>
    <p>test post 1 post test 1</p>
    <p>testing post rou<h4></h4></p>
    <p><img src="/file/910947981668461269.png" width="15" height="15"></p>
  <div>
  <div>
    <p>last post</p>
    <p>latest post</p>
    <p><img src="/file/627966214611942166.png" width="15" height="15"></p>
  <div>
<div>
```

I tried using css grid and flex but i could not get the result i want